# I cannot install using NPM and I get an error

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, command-line-interface

I have been trying to make a vite project as well as install some packages into some already existing projects in vscode yet when I do this I get the error of:

```
npm ERR! code EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1123:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/chimera/.npm/_logs/2022-11-12T23_58_02_327Z-debug-0.log
```

I have no idea how to fix this and it is quite annoying as I am not able to make or change any projects ): I also have tried searching this on StackOverflow and I get a similar error but none of the fixes I have tried seems to do anything. If you know how to solve this could you please explain why this happened ): I am also finding *and I don't know if this is related to it or not* that my terminals take forever to load when before when I opened one they took less than a second to do so? Also, I am using Ubuntu (The latest version) and previously just used the latest version of node and there is where I got the error, the moment I downgraded to node v16 it went away. The command I tried running was the command for creating a new react project and also to adding daisyui to a project I had.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You do need to provided more info about your environment, like OS type and version, Node and npm version, and last but not least, which commands you tried to run.

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz There we go :D!